# Missing tabular cell

Tags: columns, tabularray

I apologise for the inconvenience these couple days. Hopefully this is the last of my table. I have made the following:

[image]

But I want to make this table (compiled in Word):

[image]

The top cell in the third cell keeps vanishing. My MWE is as follow:

```
            \documentclass[12pt]{article}
            \usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
            \usepackage[font=scriptsize,
                    labelfont=bf]{caption}
            \usepackage[xcdraw]{xcolor}
            \usepackage{tabularray}
            \usepackage{pdflscape}
            \UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
            \usepackage{lipsum}
            \begin{document}
            \begin{table}[ht]
            \centering
        \caption{Contact Angles measured at various positions for three Glass Samples - same batch}
        \begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
         colspec={*{5}{X[c,m]}},
         colsep=4pt,
         row{1}={rowsep=3ex},
         row{2}={rowsep=1ex}}
        \SetCell[r=2]{c}{Text is here}
    & \SetCell[c=3]{c}{There is text in this box}
    & \SetCell[r=2]{c}{Wow, some more text} &\\
        &Left &M &Right     \\
        2 & Centre &S3 &S4 &S5      \\
        3 & Right &S3 &S4 &S5   \\
        4 & Reference &20 &20 &20 \\
        \end{tblr}
        \end{table}
        \end{document}
```

I can not thank you guys enough for your advice/input in these times. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the original, two `&` were missing right before `\SetCell[r=2]{c}{Wow, some more text}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[font=scriptsize,
        labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Contact Angles measured at various positions for three Glass Samples - same batch}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
colspec={*{5}{X[c,m]}},
colsep=4pt,
row{1}={rowsep=3ex},
row{2}={rowsep=1ex}}
\SetCell[r=2]{c}{Text is here}
& \SetCell[c=3]{c}{There is text in this box}
&&& \SetCell[r=2]{c}{Wow, some more text} \\
  & Left      & Middle & Right        \\
2 & Centre    & S3     & S4    & S5   \\
3 & Right     & S3     & S4    & S5   \\
4 & Reference & 20     & 20    & 20   \\
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so so much. I was pulling my hair trying to figure whether I was missing some & characters.